# How can I set Hibernate FetchType not to Eager or Lazy but to "none" so that it does NOT load the stuff itself?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql, hibernate-mapping

I have an Hibernate class that has fields like this:

```
@OneToMany(
    orphanRemoval = true,
    mappedBy = "others",
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<AnotherEntity> otherEntities;
```

We have lazy loading on, so that it does not load everything at once.
But I want to have it so that it does not load the stuff at all - if I want to load it, I will use a (Hibernate) query that gets all the necessary information.
If I load only the main objects, nothing else should be loaded with them.

entity.getOtherEntities() should return null - even if there is data.

Is it somehow possible to achieve this?

Comment: My understanding is that lazy loading would only load the referred collection if you tried to access it via some sort of getter.  Then what is wrong with this behavior?  Just access the other entities collection when you want to use, and Hibernate will not load anything up until that point.

Comment: I want to define in the repository what data should be fetched. If I say that I do not want otherEntities, then they should be null. I want to have this because then I use Converters that will convert all this stuff to other objects - if the data is there.
Those converters will (with Lazy loading) load more and more data. I would like to have the restriction on the entity side and let those my converters convert all data that they get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several, exemplary options:

1. You can use projection (an interface with getters and setters for fields you need to fetch). [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections) an example.
2. You can pull up fields to superclass (using `MappedSuperclass`) and use it to fetch only the necessary data.
3. Using `EntityManager.createQuery` you can specify fields using jpql, then only declared fields will be fetched.